# Python startswith() for loop and if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop, startswith

I want to run a for loop in an array list and print anything out that has the word 'monkey' in it. I wrote the following code below but it is giving me an error. I'm not too sure what i am doing wrong. Any help would be great, thank you.

```
a= "monkeybanana"
b= "monkeyape"
c= "apple"
list= [a, b, c]


print "The words that start with monkey are:"

for k in words:
    if list.startswith('monkey'):
        print list
```

Comment: Try with `if k.startswith('monkey'):` and `print k`

Comment: if k.startswith('monkey'): ?

Comment: where is words coming from?

Comment: I see a lot of issues, but @Pynchia has the best answer. However, for future reference, please include the error that it gives you. In this case, it probably tells you something like "'words' is not defined". That's a great place to start.

Answer (score 9):

you need to change it to

```
a= "monkeybanana"
b= "monkeyape"
c= "apple"
lst = [a, b, c]


print "The words that start with monkey are:"

for k in lst:
    if k.startswith('monkey'):
        print k
```

Basically you are iterating on `words`, but that name doesn't exist.

Then with

```
if list.startswith('monkey'):
```

the code checks the list of words starts with `monkey`, not the element of the list (`k`)

Finally

```
print list
```

prints the whole list, not the current element of it

Note: the whole algorithm can be reduced to one line using [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

```
print filter(lambda x: x.startswith('monkey'), lst)
```

Note2: avoid naming variable with names python uses already. If you use `list` as a variable name, it will shadow the built-in `list` function and you won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing a different piece of data. Try:

```
a= "monkeybanana"
b= "monkeyape"
c= "apple"
list= [a, b, c]


print "The words that start with monkey are:"

for k in list:
    if k.startswith('monkey'):
        print k
```

Answer (score 0):

There are errors printed by Python, you should definitely check those!

What you want to do is to check *every word in the list* to see if it has 'monkey' inside.
What you wrote (kind of) translates to: for every word in the list check the list to see if it starts with 'monkey'.

Of course if you want to print the word that has 'monkey' in it, you'll have to print the word (`print k` in your scenario, since that's the word you're currently at wihle going over the list), not the list itself.

For a quick answer:

If you want to see if 'monkey' is in a word (as the question says) in the list:

```
a = "monkeybanana"
b = "monkeyape"
c = "apple"
list = [a, b, c]


print "The words that start with monkey are:"

for k in list:
    if 'monkey' in k:
        print k
```

If you want to see if 'monkey' is in is at the beginning of a word (as the title and code say) in the list:

```
a = "monkeybanana"
b = "monkeyape"
c = "apple"
list = [a, b, c]


print "The words that start with monkey are:"

for k in list:
    if k.startswith('monkey'):
        print k
```